# Dynamic value in property for ColdFusion ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is it possible in ColdFusion that a non-persistent property could have a dynamic value?

An example would be

```
   Item.cfc

   property name="myID" length="100"    type="string"   fieldtype="id" generator="guid";

   property name="hasImageFlag"  persistent=false  default="{isNull(getItem().getIcon())};

   property name="Icon"  fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="imageID" cfc="image" lazy="true";
```

So in this example hasImageFlag could just be isNull(getItem().getIcon()) which would return true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that in cfproperty. For two reasons.

1. It simply does not allow a dynamic default. So you can't even do default="#arrayNew(1)#"
2. In your case, the getItem() method of this class will not exist yet while this code is running.

When I have needed dynamic defaults, I have done it in the init() constructor method so that it happens immediately after the object is created.

Comment: Am I right is saying the init() only runs on new enitity entity?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems like you're trying to re-invent Hibernate formulas, which are accessible through  CF's ORM system as well.

Comment: I am serializing the ORM entity. I cannot get mapped properties so I want a flag to let my application know it needs to make another call to pull it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Hibernate event listeners? Ben Nadel has [a decent primer here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1691-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Understand-ORM-Events-Thanks-John-Whish-.htm).

You might be able to do what you want using preLoad or postLoad...